# NGINX Source code; problem for ngx_cdecl and char *const *argv

Tags: c, nginx

I was reading Nginx source code and in here : [nginx.c](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/nginx.c#L194)
I have two questinos.

1. What is `ngx_cdecl`? and why is it here?
2. what is `char *const *argv`? and why not `char *argv[]`?

Thank You.

Comment: I don't know ngx in details but my guess is: 1) `ngx_cdecl` probably specifies the call convention to be like C. 2) If you forget the `const` in `char *const *argv` it means exavtly the same as `char *argv[]`. The `const` part just add the pointed to pointers are const.

Comment: 2) the `const` means that I can't change argv values ?

Comment: the strings that `argv[]` points to are in read-only memory, so you never could change them

Comment: So, If I don't put ```const``` or put it. It doesn't matter right?